# Function and data format for doing vector-based clustering in R

Tags: r, vector, cluster-analysis, correlation, cosine-similarity

I need to run clustering on the correlations of data row vectors, that is, instead of using individual variables as clustering predictor variables, I intend to use the correlations between the vector of variables between data rows.

Is there a function in R that does vector-based clustering. If not and I need to do it manually, what is the right data format to feed in a function such as cmeans or kmeans? 
Say, I have m variables and n data rows, the m variables constitute one vector for each data row.  so I have a n X n matrix for correlation or cosine. Can this matrix be plugged in the clustering function directly or certain processing is required?

Many thanks.

Comment: You could get started with `?kmeans` and `example(kmeans)`. Also, http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html

Answer (score 1):

R clustering is often a bit limited. This is a design limitation of R, since it heavily relies on low-level C code for performance. The fast kmeans implementation included with R is an example of such a low-level code, that in turn is tied to using Euclidean distance.

There are a dozen of extensions and alternatives available in the community around R. There are PAM, CLARA and CLARANS for example. They aren't *exactly* k-means, but closely related. There should be a "spherical k-means" somewhere, that is sensible for cosine distance. There is the whole family of hierarchical clusterings (which scale rather badly - usually `O(n^3)`, with `O(n^2)` in a few exceptions - but are very easy to understand conceptually).

If you want to explore some more clustering options, have a look at [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/), it should allow clustering (with various methods, including k-means) by correlation based distances (and it also includes such distance functions). It's **not R**, though, but Java. So if you are bound to using R, it won't work for you.

Comment: I downvoted for 2 reasons: (1) There are 93 R packages that provide clustering methods, some very commonly used and cited. (2) Question specifically asked for solution in R.

Comment: Well, still they often are quite limited. When you take the kmeans clustering of R (itself, not some extension), you just cannot plug in a different distance or a similarity matrix. Which may even be the reason that there are so many extension packages. There is quite some overlap and inconsistency.

Comment: Nice clarification. I learned something new, and reversed my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your correlation matrix into a dissimilarity matrix,
for instance `1-cor(x)` (or `2-cor(x)` or `1-abs(cor(x))`).

```
# Sample data
n <- 200
k <- 10
x <- matrix( rnorm(n*k), nr=k )
x <- x * row(x) # 10 dimensions, with less information in some of them

# Clustering
library(cluster)
r <- pam(1-cor(x), diss=TRUE, k=5)

# Check the results
plot(prcomp(t(x))$x[,1:2], col=r$clustering, pch=16, cex=3)
```